# Why is DownloadComplete event only firing once from BitmapImage?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this

```
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            Photo = new BitmapImage(new Uri(goodPhotoList[8]));
            Photo.DownloadCompleted += delegate(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
            {
                //called only once!!
            };
        });
```

I need to call the downloadcompleted event everytime I load a new image (from goodPhotoList[8])

but it only works once, never firing again

what am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have a loop around this call? If you don't then how do you expect more than one download to be triggered? Maybe you need to iterate over the goodPhotoList rather than pick out only the element at index 8?

Comment: getting the element is not a issue, event the element 8 is always returning different image, that is just for debuging purpose. Yes, there is a Dispatcher Timer calling it evert few seconds;

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with the timer? Do you have a more complete code sample that includes the timer?

Comment: The `DownloadCompleted` event will only be fired when the `IsDownloading` property was true. If the BitmapImage is loaded from a local file URL or from cache, `IsDownloading` will be false.